# TortoiseSVN overlay icons not appearing when they should

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I checked out some folders from SVN to my local PC.  When the checkout completed, I checked the folder structure and the files in the folder.  Some files have the green SVN status icon, but some files don't.  What happened?

Comment: Can you give an example of the files/filenames which aren't green?
Are they another colour or a different icon?

Answer (score 4):

This just happened to me after logging-off and logging back on.

Simply run the TSVNCache.exe process from the bin folder where TortoiseSVN is installed and the icons should appear.

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseSVN builds up a list of status icons in a background process that has low priority. The status icons can lag behind 'reality' by a few minutes.  This behaviour is governed by the tortoise options dialog, as detailed [on this page of the Tortoise documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-overlay).

You can look in the Properties dialog, on the Subversion tab, to see the text status; it's always accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen before, especially when viewing the directory list in the left side pane of windows explorer. The icons are not always correct in reflecting the actual status of the directories or files. Close windows explorer and reopen or do a refresh.